# Ng-repeat using click to show/hide not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the directive I'm using, there's a list of names that is dynamically generated from JSON. When you click on a name, it is suppose to show/hide a window with more info on that name. What happens instead is it shows/hides every window for every name in the list. I want it to just show/hide the window for the one I click on.

JS:

```
app.directive("taskListing", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "/templates/elements/tasklisting.html",
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, $sce){
                element.on("click", function(){
                    angular.element("tbody.task-tbody tr").toggleClass("hidden"); 
                    });
                },


            };

        });
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="taskController">
<tbody class="task-tbody" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="task.title != ''">
    <tr >
        <td>
            <span class='tasks-task'>{{task.title}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!--This table row is toggled show/hide-->
     <tr class="hidden" bgcolor="#F8F8F8" >
        <td>
            <strong>Description:</strong>
            <p>{{task.description}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html?

Comment: You toggle every tr element. You probably want to toggleclass on your "element" variable (or some child/parent of it). Angular.element != element

Comment: @Rob I added the HTML

Comment: @Noppey I am toggling the <tr>

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong query in `angular.element("tbody.task-tbody tr")` you must specify which tr you want to show

first hide all tr and then show only one with specific ID for example

```
angular.element("tbody.task-tbody tr").addClass('hidden');
angular.element("#task_8").removeClass('hidden');
```

specify task id in template:

```
<tr id="task_{{task.id}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to be certain without your HTML, but I believe that your issue is `angular.element("tbody.task-tbody tr").toggleClass("hidden");`.

`angular.element(document)` aliases a jQuery function ([ng docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)). In this case it is aliasing a selector and selecting all of the rows in your `"tbody.task-tbody tr"`. Thus, when you are calling `.toggleClass("hidden")`, jQuery is applying the "hidden" class to all of those elements.

Given that you only want to hide the element that has been clicked on, you can use the provided reference to the element in the directive to apply "hidden" exclusively to that element.

For example:

```js
app.directive("taskListing", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/templates/elements/tasklisting.html",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, $sce){
      element.on("click", function(){
        // use element instead of 'angular.element'
        element.toggleClass("hidden");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `element` you're listening the click event is the directive itself, so everytime you click on something inside the directive, every `<tr>` will have the toggleClass performed.

So instead of `element.on("click",....` you should do `element.find("tbody.task-tbody tr").on("click",...`.

And if you only want to toggle the visiblity of the `<tr>` with the #F8F8F8 background, I suggest you add a class to target it more easily.

[edit]
Your link function would be:

```
function(scope, element) {
  element.find("tbody.task-tbody tr").on("click", function() {
    this.toggleClass("hidden"); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Your approach will yield same result as op. You are going to end up finding all the `tr` elements.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to say that in the handler, you must use `this` to refer to the clicked element instead of `angular.element...` => `this.toggleClass("hidden")`.